# Stop Bootstrap table stretching to full screen width and adding extra space to the cells

Tags: html, css, bootstrap-4

I have a table that fits on screens up to 600px. When the screen size becomes larger than 600px, the table grows to fill the screen and gives each column a lot of extra spacing on the right of each cell.

How do I remove this stop the table from growing and remove extra unwanted space so that the next column starts at the end of the largest cell from the previous column?

```html
<head>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css"
    integrity="sha384-Gn5384xqQ1aoWXA+058RXPxPg6fy4IWvTNh0E263XmFcJlSAwiGgFAW/dAiS6JXm" crossorigin="anonymous"> -->

</head>
<table class="table table-dark">
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th scope="col">Stat</th>
      <th scope="col">First</th>
      <th scope="col">Last</th>
      <th scope="col">Handle</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <th scope="row">Highest Money Reached</th>
      <td>Mark</td>
      <td>Otto</td>
      <td>@mdo</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <th scope="row">2</th>
      <td>Jacob</td>
      <td>Thornton</td>
      <td>@fat</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <th scope="row">3</th>
      <td>Larry</td>
      <td>the Bird</td>
      <td>@twitter</td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

The code is also on this [JsFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/L7wpfzad/)

Comment: Do you mean that you want to reallocate that space to other columns, or that you don't want the table to stretch to the full screen width?

Comment: @FluffyKitten yes I dont want it to stretch. The amount of space the words take up is all I want.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are using Bootstrap classes, and the Bootstrap `.table` sets the with of the table to `width:100%;`. You could remove the `table` class from your table HTML and that would your - however it also affects some of the styling also.

Instead, to prevent your table from stretching to the full screen width (unless it needs to), you just need to add the following to your CSS:

```
table.table { width:auto; }
```

Just make sure that this is included *after* your Bootstrap CSS, and don't forget to include the `.table` in your CSS selector to override the Bootstrap class.

**Working Example:**

```css
table.table { width:auto;}
```

```html
<head>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css"
    integrity="sha384-Gn5384xqQ1aoWXA+058RXPxPg6fy4IWvTNh0E263XmFcJlSAwiGgFAW/dAiS6JXm" crossorigin="anonymous">

</head>
<table class="table table-dark">
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th scope="col">Stat</th>
      <th scope="col">First</th>
      <th scope="col">Last</th>
      <th scope="col">Handle</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <th scope="row">Highest Money Reached</th>
      <td>Mark</td>
      <td>Otto</td>
      <td>@mdo</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <th scope="row">2</th>
      <td>Jacob</td>
      <td>Thornton</td>
      <td>@fat</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <th scope="row">3</th>
      <td>Larry</td>
      <td>the Bird</td>
      <td>@twitter</td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

Comment: Works great with Bootstrap 5.1 as well! I did `<table class="table table-sm table-bordered" style="width: auto">` to make this apply to only one particular table.

Answer (score 1):

In Bootstrap 5.2 you can use class `w-auto`.

```
<table class="table table-dark w-auto">
    <thead>
        ...
    </thead>
</table>
```